# Windows Forms casting Button class

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Please explain.

In line 3 I dont know why class button is used to cast the sender object,

how does sender object functions in line 3

and what is the reason of using Button class in line 3?

```
1. private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
2. {
3.      Button btn = (Button) sender;
4.      textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + btn.Text;
5. }
```

Comment: The sender is a typeless object, you must tell the compiler that this object is a Button, so it can work as a button. That's why you cast it as button. Could do `Button btn = sender as Button` as well.

Comment: Try to use `sender.Text` and see what happens if you don't cast to `Button` first.

Comment: click is a generic event which can be raised by a button, a window or really any kind of control. Therefore the handling of a click event is handled in a generic manner: the "Click" method looks the same for all kinds of controls. It contains a 'sender' argument which specifies the source of the click event, eg which was the control which caused the click event to be raised. Therefore you will have to cast it when you need to reference the sender as a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the declaration

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

the only guarantee is that `sender` is of type `object`; and `object` instance *doesn't have* `Text` property

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // sender.Text doesn't compile - sender being Object doesn't have Text property
  textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + sender.Text;
}
```

so you have cast to a type which has `Text` property, a most accurate way to [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Control: Button, TextBox, Panel etc.
  Control ctrl = sender as Control;

  // If we succeed in cast (i.e. sender is a Control)
  if (ctrl != null)
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ctrl.Text;
}
```

When explicit cast to `Button`

```
Button btn = (Button) sender; // dangerous code
```

can be dangerous: you may want, say, add `myPanel.Click += button_Click` while you don't check cast's result (treat `myPanel` as `Button` and let it be).

Answer (score 2):

These event handlers all include the `object sender` parameter to indicate which object instance raised the event. This allows you to re-use the event handler for multiple buttons:

```
button1.Click += button_Click;
button2.Click += button_Click;
```

The cast to `Button` is only because the author of the code has *remembered* that he/she is only using this event handler for `Button`s - reusing this handler for other classes would cause an `InvalidCastException` to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Because c# doesn't know 
Which class is used so you must tell the compiler that object is of type Button.

if the object isn't of type button you wil get an InvalidCastException

a cleaner way would be

```
Button button = sender as Button;
if(button != null)
{
   //action
}
```

Comment: last question why use if(button != null) or (check expression for null)?

Comment: when casting like this `(Button)` and the object is not a button you will get an InvalidCastException. If you cast with the `as` keyword and the object is not of type button it returns null